# Sending emails from mu4e and gnupg in emacs stopped

Tags: emacs, gnupg

I am trying to figure out why I cannot send anymore emails in Emacs and mu4e package and gnupg tools for encryption. Although it worked flawlessly for a while it suddenly stopped. I have this error now: 
apply: Searching for program: No such file or directory, /usr/local/bin/gpg1

Comment: Okay I did some progress with it, and now says: Error while decrypting with "/usr/local/bin/gpg1":
gpg: Invalid option "--pinentry-mode"

Answer (score 1):

To save an answer for other users. I installed gnupg21 following all instructions on unlinking other versions of gpg versions on my machine, and killed an agents with this `gpgconf --kill gpg-agent` this seems to fix the problem.